# How to know if there is a user in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to create a view that lets a user create a "profile" but if the user already has a profile then the user is redirected to page where the user can see other people's profiles(in order to see this other people's profiles, the user has to create a profile as a requirement), for doing this proces I have 2 templates, one that has a form to create the profile and other one that displays other user's profile. The error is that every user is redirected to mates-form.html even the ones that already have a profile. So far I think that the error is on the views.py file.

models.py

```
    class Mates(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates')
        users_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_requests")
        req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
    def matesmain(request):
        contents = Mates.objects.all()
        if contents == request.user:
            context = {
                'contents': contents,
                'form_mates': MatesForm(),
            }
            print("nice3")
            return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request,  'mates-form.html')

    def mates(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form_mates.is_valid():
                instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
                return redirect('mates-main')
                print('succesfully uploded')

        else:
            form_mates = MatesForm()
            print('didnt upload')
        context = {
               'form_mates': form_mates,
               'contents': Mates.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request, 'mates-form.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
    class MatesForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Mates
            fields = ('req_bio', 'req_image',)
            exclude = ['user']
```

mates.html

```
    {% if contents %}
        {% for content in contents %}
            Here is where the user can see other user's profiles
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

mates-form.html

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form_mates.as_p }}
    </form>
```

If you have any questions or if you need to see more code please let me know in the comments, also I thought of other way for doing these removing the if statements from matesmain view and just using them on the html but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the user will have only one profile so Instead of `ManyToOneRelation` i.e. `ForeignKey` using `OneToOneRelation` with the User Model would be better.

```
 class Mates(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates')
```

Now while creating the profile you can check whether the user profile already exists or not like this:

```
def mates(request):
     if Mates.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
         return redirect('redirect_to_some_view_you_want') 
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```